# Font problem in Joomla

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table, in joomla I'm getting the following data:

```
1. fc k��ln - vfl wolfsburg
germany 1. bundesliga
```

so I created a test page, I set up the header as utf-8, and everything was fine, I received the wanted data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4e36e64eb34d2
            [team1] => 1. FC Köln
            [team2] => VFL Wolfsburg
            [league] => Germany 1. Bundesliga
            [sport] => Soccer
            [time] => 2011-08-06 15:30:00
        )

)
```

I also check the joomla header and it's contains the charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need some extra commands before I'm fetching the data?

Comment: You'd probably have to check the encoding used in the table. Similar as in your other [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4227/character-set-encoding-in-a-table).

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using ???

Comment: 5.1.53, I'm printing out some other text(like éáűüö) this texts are appear correctly, bet the data which are coming from the table are not good. I created a test page just for testing, and there I got the right strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER : I do not use Joomla

This is really a Joomla Problem [not a MySQL Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852260/does-mysql-collation-type-need-to-match-php-page-charset-type/852563#852563). By any chance, are you using Joomla 1.0 ?

Here is something showing in the Joomla Documentation how to [activate the MySQL Query SET NAMES using utf8](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_deal_with_UTF-8_issues_in_Joomla%21_1.0.x_series%3F?).

You may also need to play with the collation setting within the DB Connection

Here are the default settings for MySQL 5.5.12 running in Windows 7

```
mysql> show variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                           |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                          |
| character_set_connection | latin1                          |
| character_set_database   | latin1                          |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                          |
| character_set_results    | latin1                          |
| character_set_server     | latin1                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                            |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\MySQL_5.5.12\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Try setting the character set and collation variables within the session or set this in my.cnf and restart mysql